# Use Rsync with HTTP

Tags: rsync, embedded, html

Is it possible to use `rsync` with an HTML POST request? If so what would the `rsync` command look like?

For example let's say using HTML5 I have this :

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

This produces a webpage having two buttons with which you can upload a directory of files from the local computer. Could I use `rsync` at this point to only download and update files in the directory which are needed, (i.e., firmware update).  I don't want to have to download the whole file system because that's slow.

Comment: Let me see if I understand.  You are hosting a website that includes some HTML similar to what you have posted.  You would like visitors to be able to upload large directories of files via this website.  However, instead of having the entire contents of the selected directories to be uploaded, you would like to leverage `rsync` to determine which files have changed and only upload the files on the visitor's computer that have been modified since the last time they uploaded their directories?

Comment: You said it perfect. Thats what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I suspect this is not possible (all visitors would need to have rsync installed), but an important aspect is knowing what server you're using.  Is it Apache?

Comment: Currently using thttpd.